# Output SQL table with

Tags: php, sql

I am very new to PHP, but have done some reading on it. I have tried this varies ways and can't find a solution, but feel that there should definitely be one.

I am trying to display a SQL table with PHP - this is easy, I know.
Next I am displaying all my data (images) in columns to run vertically (to make it display nicely).
 - for it to run display in columns, this is what my mind came up with:

- get the amount of data in SQL database (25 rows for example) $dataoutput
- divide it by 4 (4 columns) $dataoutput / 4 = 5
- display the table with a FOR function (run only if SQL result is smaller than the result (5)
- add a  at the end of the 5 outputted images.
- Get the process to start all over again for 4 times (4 columns).

I've changed the code back to the basics - so it will works again.

```
<?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM allthaimgs ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            ?>  

        <div class="column">

            <div class="colimgdiv">
                <img src="../imgs/galary/zoom.png" class="zoomimgincol">
                <div class="blktrsprt"></div>
                <img src="../imgs/galary/imgs/<?php echo $row["imgs"];?>" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(<?php echo $row["id"];?>)" class="theimg">
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php 
                }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";

        } 
        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Comment: You can limit your database record output by adding the LIMIT clause in your sql string as `LIMIT 5`;

Comment: Thanks Karlo. I am aware of the LIMIT function. That is not what I require. I would like to get 1.the amount of rows in SQL table. 2. Divide it by 4 (four columns). 5. And put a piece of html after each row output(the result of number 4) (</div><div class"newrow">)